# Kendo UI Grid Data Binding

Tags: ajax, json, kendo-ui

I am having a heck of a time rebinding the grid to data received from an AJAX call. The dates lose their formatting.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viewModel;

        $(function () {
            // Load Data
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: "/Kendo/Home/GetData"
            }).success(function (result) {
                viewModel = new kendo.observable(result);
            });

            // Create Grid
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: viewModel.People,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                DOB: { type: "date" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                    { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name" },
                    { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
                    { field: "DOB", title: "Date of Birth", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" }
                ],
                editable: true
            });

            $(document).on("click", "#btn-save", function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Kendo/Home/Save",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(viewModel),
                    contentType: "application/json"
                }).success(function (result) {
                    var g = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                    viewModel = new kendo.observable(result);
                    g.dataSource.data(viewModel.People);

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<div id="grid"></div>
<div id="view">
    <input data-bind="value: firstName" />
    <input data-bind="value: lastName" />
    <button id="btn-save">Save</button>
</div>
```

The initial data loaded is this:

```
{"People":[{"FirstName":"Sam","LastName":"Striano","DOB":"\/Date(215420400000)\/"},{"FirstName":"Karson","LastName":"Striano","DOB":"\/Date(321609600000)\/"}]}
```

The data returned from the AJAX call (via the Save button) is this:

```
{"People":[{"FirstName":"Sam 1234","LastName":"Striano","DOB":"\/Date(216288000000)\/"},{"FirstName":"Karson 1234","LastName":"Striano","DOB":"\/Date(322473600000)\/"}]}
```

Comment: Did you try with templates? Something like: `template: '#= kendo.toString(DOB,"MM/dd/yyyy") #'`

Comment: @Pabloker I did and it works until I try and rebind the result from the ajax call, then the formatting goes away. Do I have to reapply the data source schema?

Comment: I'm using kendo grid + MVC3 like this: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding. I solved dates formating using client templates.

Comment: I replied to your formal ticket.